# Phoenix, Json and Unix Timestamps

Tags: json, datetime, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm exporting data from SQL Server in json format so I can import it into my Phoenix app. What I'm not sure about is how I should deal with dates. At the moment I'm exporting dates as a Unix timestamp. Here's a sample:

```
[
  { "Log": { "Start": 1319734790, "End": 0, "Comment": "" },
  { "Log": { "Start": 1319732847, "End": 1319734790, "Comment": "Had lunch today" }
]
```

In Phoenix/Elixir what's the best way to convert a Unix timestamp into a DateTime object? I'm assuming because I'm inserting into an Ecto database, that I need to use an Ecto DateTime object.

Comment: http://michal.muskala.eu/2015/07/30/unix-timestamps-in-elixir.html

Comment: Also, if you are planning to work with time a lot, it may make sense to use `Timex` library, which makes things way easier.

Comment: In the end, because I have control over the json, I used strings in iso date format. These strings are automatically converted for a DateTime field and I didn't have to do any manual conversions

Comment: @Dogbert The link you gave is 404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get an Erlang-style datetime tuple from a unix timestamp like this:

```
epoch = :calendar.datetime_to_gregorian_seconds({{1970, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}})
datetime = :calendar.gregorian_seconds_to_datetime(your_unix_timestamp + epoch)
```

This will have `datetime` in tuple format like `{{2016, 4, 28}, {00:50:12}}`

You can convert that tuple to an `Ecto.DateTime` with `Ecto.DateTime.from_erl/1`

But check your assumptions. Maybe you need timezone information. And I see you have the value `0` in your example. Do you really want 1970-01-01 00:00:00 to represent "no value"?

Comment: Not really, no. I was going to test for 0 and convert that to nil. I was also leaving timezone info until the import was functional, but yes, timezone is important.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DateTime.from_unix/2` to transform unix timestamp to DateTime struct, like below

```
# Change unit to millisecond, the default is second
timestamps |> DateTime.from_unix(:millisecond)
```

When you have a DateTime construct, you can just pass it to Ecto models field. Ecto supports 2 field types `naive_datetime` and `utc_datetime` which corresponding to `NaiveDateTime` and `DateTime` structs. You can choose what you want and Ecto will do the transformation for you.

Finally, both 2 field types will be transformed to the same type in database, i.e. `timestamp without time zone` in PostgreSQL. So you can easily switch the model schema.

Comment: I quite like this, it's nice and short